# How to access variables defined in try catch scope in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have below piece of code , where I am trying to access a variable defined in try but it's not accessible , what could be done to fix it.

```
  try{
       $X = get-X 
     }
  catch
     {
            Manage exception
     }

   write-host $X
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this and it looks like a bug. Declaring the variable outside try block does not solve the scope issue. As soon you leave the try block value of $a gets reset to what it was before you entered try block. so if you want to access $a after executing try{} you need to access it as $global:a inside the try {} block.

Comment: your tip helped me a lot and I was convinced it was a bug as you say until I changed my variables within my function to private scope i.e. `$private:myVar`, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6#scope-modifiers

Answer (score 2):

I added a comment to a previous answer but felt the need to post an example Powershell function (within the context of a class) to demonstrate that using scoping (`$private` in my case) addresses this issue:

```
[String[]] static GetSRVHostPort([String]$srvRecord) {
        [String] $private:myHost, $private:myPort
        try {
            $private:myHost, $private:myPort = Resolve-DnsName -Type 'srv' $srvRecord | ForEach-Object { $_.Name, $_.Port }
        } catch {
            Write-Output("Exception thrown whilst resolving DNS SRV record [$srvRecord]: $_")
        }
        return $private:myHost, $private:myPort
    }
```

For futher details of scopes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-6#scope-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

For me this return all the processes as simple `get-process` command does:

```
try
{
   $a = get-process
}
catch
{
    write-error "Some error occurred"
}

$a
```

Comment: This answer is insinuating that there is a problem with the OP's variable assignment and that he 'can' access the variable, but it's not a value he's expecting.

Answer (score 0):

As @Christian notes, it should work fine the way you have it.  If `$x` is not getting populated, perhaps `Get-X` is not returning anything, or an error is occurring.

You can always go with the pattern of declaring the variable up top:

```
$a = <default value, or $null>
try
{
   $a = get-process
}
catch
{
    write-error "Some error occurred"
}
$a
```

Answer (score 0):

For the try statement to actually catch the failure of Get-Variable of a variable that does not exist. I had to add the `-ErrorAction` switch. The default `ErrorAction` is to continue, this did not allow the try statement to catch the error.

```
$testName = Get-Variable -Name $variableName -ErrorAction Stop
```